# Is there a better way to emulate \x interpolation?

Tags: regex, perl, interpolation

I need to interpolate `\x{}` (wide hex char) in a string in the same way as Perl does. The double evaluation in my code makes me doubt that it is the best solution.

```
s/(\\x\{[a-fA-F0-9]+\})/'"'.$1.'"'/ee;
# or
s
 /( \\x \{ [a-fA-F0-9]+ \} )
 / '"' . $1 . '"'
 /xee;
```

Is there an easier and more readable way?

For instance, the above regex changes the string "Spa\x{df}" to "Spaß".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only uses one `e`:

```
s/\\x\{([A-Fa-f0-9]+)\}/chr hex $1/eg;
```